# Create polygon using edge lengths and area

Tags: geometry

Four-sided convex land plots are usually denoted with edge lengths and area.

How do I create a Polygon Object with these parameters in Mathematica ?

Comment: I tried tinkering on Wolfram Alpha to get the inner angles but so far I couldn't think of any way to accomplish it :/

Comment: You can write the area of a convex quadrilateral in terms of the angle between the diagonals and edge lengths or angle between different sides and the side lengths, etc. Try formulating the problem using those...

Comment: Writing some code to bruteforce it at the moment. Are there any 'more elegant' solutions ?

Comment: As noted by rm, you might be able to use [Bretschneider's formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BretschneidersFormula.html) to reckon out admissible ranges of diagonal lengths. From this, you can build up the two triangles that comprise your quadrilateral.

Comment: I tried something I try often: writing constraints using symbolic geometric regions functionality. What stopped me this time was this jewel: `RegionDisjoint[Line[{{x1, x1}, {x2, y2}}], Line[{{x3, y3}, {x4, y4}}]]` -> `(* 39715 *)`. When Mathematica lacks geometric intuition, it compensates it by providing unbelievable amount of lack of intuition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll illustrate one way with an example. The idea is to fix the first two points at origin and on positive x axis, set up equations for the lengths and the area, solve them, then get rid of some symmetric solutions by insisting the third point have positive `y` value.

I cribbed the area formula from some random Internet site so I'm certain it's correct.

```
lens = {3, 1, 4, 2};
area = 3;

p1 = {0, 0};
p2 = {First[lens], 0};
p3 = {x3, y3};
p4 = {x4, y4};
{a, b, c, d} = lens;
psq = (p3 - p1).(p3 - p1);
qsq = (p4 - p2).(p4 - p2);
polys = {(p3 - p2).(p3 - p2) - lens[[2]]^2,
   (p4 - p3).(p4 - p3) - lens[[3]]^2,
   p4.p4 - lens[[4]]^2, 
   area^2 - 1/16 (4*psq*qsq - (a^2 + c^2 - b^2 - d^2)^2)};

sol = Solve[polys == 0];
Select[sol, (y3 /. #) >= 0 &] // N

(* Out[198]= {{y4 -> -1.88729833462, x4 -> 0.661895003862, 
  y3 -> 0.536554646919, x3 -> 3.8438655763}, {y4 -> 1.11270166538, 
  x4 -> -1.66189500386, y3 -> 0.733275958395, x3 -> 2.32006884993}} *)
```

--- edit ---
Motivated by the response from @Michael E2, I packaged this as a `Module` and used `NSolve` (which, under the hood, also computes a Groebner basis over `InexactNumbers`).

```
quad[lens_, area_, x_, y_] := Module[
  {p1, p2, p3, p4, a, b, c, d, psq, qsq, polys, sol},
  p1 = {0, 0};
  p2 = {First[lens], 0};
  p3 = {x[3], y[3]};
  p4 = {x[4], y[4]};
  {a, b, c, d} = lens;
  psq = (p3 - p1).(p3 - p1);
  qsq = (p4 - p2).(p4 - p2);
  polys = {(p3 - p2).(p3 - p2) - lens[[2]]^2,
    (p4 - p3).(p4 - p3) - lens[[3]]^2, p4.p4 - lens[[4]]^2,
    area^2 - 1/16 (4*psq*qsq - (a^2 + c^2 - b^2 - d^2)^2)};
  sol = NSolve[polys];
  Select[sol, With[{y3 = y[3] /. #}, Im[y3] == 0 && y3 >= 0] &]
  ]
```

I cannot say much about the relative speeds since I have not succeeded in getting both methods to work. My choice of an area formula might lead to suboptimal performance. I show the example from the @Michael E2 response; one of my answers is the same as the one indicated therein.

```
qsols = quad[{2, 3, 1, 2}, Pi, x, y]

Out[8]= {{y[4] -> 1.72915590151, x[4] -> -1.0049974469, 
  y[3] -> 2.14622307243, 
  x[3] -> -0.0961217816172}, {y[4] -> 1.95571758855, 
  x[4] -> 0.418531616287, y[3] -> 2.80744298296, 
  x[3] -> 0.942520025049}}
```

--- end edit ---

Comment: I added some timings to my answer.  Please verify their relative correctness.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I had roughly the same idea as Daniel Lichtblau, but with a playful twist that turned out to improve the speed.  (I was surprised.)  So on that basis I feel it's worth sharing.

We'll set up some polynomials that will define the desired quadrilateral.  I made the origin an explicit argument, even though later the `quadrilateral` function will use it only as `{0, 0}`.  The `Total[..]` line creates equations that specify the distance of three sides to be `s2`, `s3,`s4`. (The first side from the origin to`p`will be preassigned to`p = {s1, 0}`.  One could add the equation here, but we have the freedom to determine the position of one side of the quadrilateral.)  To these are added the equation for the area.

```
area[orig_, p_, q_, r_] := Det[{p - orig, r - orig}]/2 + Det[{r - q, p - q}]/2;

quadIdeal[s1_, s2_, s3_, s4_, A_, orig_, p_, q_, r_] := 
  Join[
   Total[Subtract @@@ Partition[{p, q, r, orig}, 2, 1]^2, {2}] - {s2, s3, s4}^2,
   {area[orig, p, q, r] - A}];
```

We use `GroebnerBasis` to reduce these polynomials.  It puts the polynomials in an order such that their roots can be solved sequentially -- a nice setup for `Fold`.  We apply `Reduce` and convert the equations it outputs to `Set`, to assign the value to the coordinate variable in the equation.  In `GroebnerBasis` we set `CoefficientDomain -> InexactNumbers`, so that any numeric arguments may be processed.  One caveat: if the area is too great, the figure is impossible and complex roots will be returned.

```
quadrilateral[s1_?NumericQ, s2_?NumericQ, s3_?NumericQ, s4_?NumericQ, A_?NumericQ] := 
  Polygon @
   Block[{x2, y2, x3, y3},
    Fold[
      Reduce[#2 == 0, Variables[#2]] /. Equal -> Set &,
      0,
      GroebnerBasis[#, Reverse@Variables[#], CoefficientDomain -> InexactNumbers] &@
        quadIdeal[s1, s2, s3, s4, A, {0, 0}, {s1, 0}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}]];
    {{0, 0}, {s1, 0}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}}
    ];
```

*Example -- "circle" (π) quadrature* :-)

```
N @ quadrilateral[2, 3, 1, 2, Pi]
```

> ```
> Polygon[{{0., 0.}, {2., 0.}, {0.94252, 2.80744}, {0.418532, 1.95572}}]
> ```

```
Graphics[quadrilateral[2, 3, 1, 2, Pi], Frame -> True]
```

[image: Polygon]

Surprisingly using `Fold` etc. this way is faster than `Solve` or `NSolve`.  **Edit - updated timings.**  On a fresh kernel everything ran a little faster today, so I'll report them with the other updates.  Also `GroebnerBasis` with `InexactNumbers` uses very high precision arithmetic apparently (perhaps a hundred digits).  One can save a little if at least one machine precision number is passed to `quadrilateral`:

```
Do[quadrilateral[2, 3, 1, 3, N @ Pi], {100}] // Timing // First

Do[quadrilateral[2, 3, 1, 3, Pi], {100}] // Timing // First

Do[Solve[quadIdeal[2, 3, 1, 3, Pi, {0, 0}, {2, 0}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}] == 0,
         {x2, y2, x3, y3}], {100}] // Timing // First

Do[NSolve[quadIdeal[2, 3, 1, 3, Pi, {0, 0}, {2, 0}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}] == 0,
          {x2, y2, x3, y3}], {100}] // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.202163
> 0.220306
> 1.774986
> 1.049178
> ```

Using @DanielLichtblau's `quad` (also a little faster with machine precision input):

```
Do[quad[{2, 3, 1, 2}, N @ Pi, x, y], {100}] // Timing // First
Do[quad[{2, 3, 1, 2}, Pi, x, y], {100}] // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 1.548769
> 1.581755
> ```

---

To see how it works, let's examine the steps.  Here are the initial polynomials.

```
quadIdeal[1, 4, 2, 5, 6, {0, 0}, {x1, 0}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}]
```

> ```
> {-16 + (1 - x2)^2 + y2^2,  -4 + (x2 - x3)^2 + (y2 - y3)^2,
>  -25 + x3^2 + y3^2,  -6 + y3/2 + 1/2 (y2 - x3 y2 - y3 + x2 y3)}
> ```

`GroebnerBasis` reduces the set to a simpler one that has the same roots.  Because of the nature of this problem and the way `GroebnerBasis` works, it turns out to be easy to solve for the roots.

```
GroebnerBasis[%, Reverse@Variables[%]]
```

> ```
> {21 - 26 x2 + 5 x2^2,  33 - 20 x2 + 17 x3, -9 + x2 + 2 y2,  -89 + 5 x2 + 17 y3}
> ```

The root of the first polynomial yields `x2`; here `Reduce` returns two equations, and when they are converted to `Set`, the second assignment overrides the first.
The second polynomial, with `x2` being found, yields `x3`.  Finally `y2` and `y3` are set, again `x2` having been set earlier.

Comment: (Not to display too many sour grapes, but...) is it possible you have a typo somewhere? In a fresh session I get: `In[4]:= N@quadrilateral[2, 3, 1, 2, Pi]

During evaluation of In[4]:= Reduce::ratnz: Reduce was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result. >>

Out[4]= Polygon[{{0., 0.}, {2.14331906606 + 2.93152121243 I, 
   0.}, {-0.355115569688 + 2.70725977699 I, 
   1.7075673539 - 0.328129099269 I}, {-1.14934382499 - 
    0.693069787178 I, -1.82998174396 + 0.435291490098 I}}]`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Yes there was a typo (an `x1` that should have been an `s1`).  Fixed now.  Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Very nice now. Offhand I am not sure what accounts for the relative speed gain. It could be any of a few things. (1) A lex basis might be faster to find than degree-reverse-lex, for this particular type of system. (2) The one-at-a-time solving might be faster, since it discards all but one root as it goes. (3) This form of back-solving might be generally faster than what NSolve does, for this type of system but for other reasons unknown. Interesting.